# Why does this Scanner error when trying to read delimiter? How do I seperate only between words?

Tags: java, file, java.util.scanner

So I am trying to get them separated but for some reason I need to add exclamations at the end which works but in the real world isn't how it is usually formatted. How could I do this without adding exclamations at the end only between words?
The text file reads:
John!Smith!85!
Matthew!Smith!82!
The code is as follows:
'''

```
package cmpsci111;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
/**
 *
 * @author Matt
 */
public class Files2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        File f = new File("scores.txt");
        String firstname = "";
        String lastname = "";
        int score = 0;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(f);
        while(input.hasNextLine()){
            input.useDelimiter("!");
            firstname = input.next();
            lastname=input.next();
            score = input.nextInt();
            System.out.println(firstname+ " "+ lastname + " " + score);
        }
        input.close();
        
    }
}
```

'''

Comment: `How could I do this without adding exclamations at the end only between words?` 
I am not really sure what you mean.

Comment: @Goion basically when using the delimeter "!" I have to put exclamations at the end like Matt!Smith!85! where I am wondering how to do it like Matt!Smith!85 as most data structures in the real world I would assume only separate the words like for example Apple, pear, orange instead of Apple, pear, orange,

Comment: You can use [string.split](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) method. In your case it will be `String[] inputSplit = input.split("!")`. All the words will be in corresponding element of array.

Answer (score 1):

useDelimiter can accept regular expression as argument.
"!|\r\n|\n|\r" can be used to separate  by ! or line ending symbols.
Text file can look like:

```
John!Smith!85
Matthew!Smith!82
```

Modified main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
    File f = new File("scores.txt");
    String firstname = "";
    String lastname = "";
    int score = 0;

    Scanner input = new Scanner(f);
    input.useDelimiter("!|\r\n|\n|\r"); //Before while loop


    while(input.hasNextLine()){
        //input.useDelimiter("!"); // No need  
        firstname = input.next();
        lastname=input.next();
        score = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println(firstname+ " "+ lastname + " " + score);
    }
    input.close();

}
```